# Migrate custom XAML build workflow to TFS 2017 extensions

Tags: xaml, tfs, build, visual-studio-extensions

I currently have a custom XAML build workflow which performs a lot of validations based on code structure, folders, file content and even database configuration.

Currently we need to consider to migrate it to TFS 2017, and I'm trying to understand the possibilities, effort and pitfalls and this is where I could use your help.

I have logic built in C# and then I look at MSDN documentation the language seems to be Javascript, GitHub samples seem to be Typescript. Am I forced to use one of this languages? any preferred one or limitations that I should be aware of? Can for instance, I connect to a database directly? or it's better to have an API and just use REST calls?

Can I for instance, use .Net object which have already some wrapped logic?

I also noticed that on the manifest file I can declare inputs, but can I somehow use outputs? For example, I have a task that does validation and in the end I would have a task to send an e-mail with the result of that validation. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in concluding that XAML builds are deprecated. The new Task based system is much more flexible and now that we even have [YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/build-yaml) support, you can move to Builds as Code.

The reason you're seeing Build Tasks in TypeScript (which is a superset of JavaScript) because of the cross platform nature of NodeJS. This allows your tasks to run on Windows, Linux and Mac. In the mean time [we also got .NET Core support.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/dotnet-core) You can also use PowerShell if that's more of your liking.

Regarding your 'can I connect to a database' question. Yes you can, if you want it is another question. This will massively slow your build down and will make your build fail if there are issues with database connectivity. I would suggest asking a second question here on Stackoverflow to describe your situation and discuss if there is a better alternative.

You can use output variables from your task and reuse these in the next tasks. That's all supported and no problem (see https://roadtoalm.com/2016/08/11/set-output-variable-in-a-powershell-vsts-build-task/ for an example).

Answer (score 1):

There are too many questions here and they are broad.

Whatever, XAML Build are deprecated in TFS 2017 and will not be available in the next version of TFS. VSTS already no longer supports them. So you need to [Migrate from XAML builds to new builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/migrate-from-xaml-builds) (vNext builds).  Also this similar thread for your reference : [Converting TFS XAML Build Custom Activities into TFS 2015 Build Tasks](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/50528ebc-8680-4f8b-a0d4-75a2aa19572f/converting-tfs-xaml-build-custom-activities-into-tfs-2015-build-tasks?forum=tfsbuild)

> **Marketplace**
>
> While you can make use of custom build tasks with XAML build there is
>   no centralized or integrated solution for browsing available tasks,
>   installing them or managing them. With the new builds you can make use
>   of the quickly-growing Visual Studio Team Services Marketplace. Here,
>   you can search and browse the many extensions currently available in
>   the [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/). 
>   See [WHY SHOULD I LEAVE XAML BUILDS](http://blog.devmatter.com/why-should-i-leave-xaml-builds/) for details.

So, you can find the existing extensions in [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) and install them to extend the build process (add correspinding tasks). You can also custom your own extension based on your specific requirements. See [Extensions overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/extend/overview).

> You can build custom applications or services that integrate with your
>   Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and Team Foundation Server (TFS)
>   accounts by using the **REST APIs** to make direct HTTP calls, or
>   utilize our **.NET Client Libraries**.
>
> Source here : [Integrating with VSTS and Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/integrate/)

To add a custom task you can reference below articles:

- [Add a build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task)
- [Reference for creating custom build tasks within extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/build-task-schema)
- [Developing a Custom Build vNext Task](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/developing-a-custom-build-vnext-task-part-1)

For the "outputs" validation, you can try it with [build alerts.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/alerts-and-notifications)